# Como usar dois sensores no Arduíno e mostrar os dados em uma aplicação C#?

Tags: c#, arduino, conexão, serial

Tenho um Código no Arduíno onde tem 1 sensor ultrassônico que mede a quantidade de liquido, e em um tanque um sensor de fluxo que mede a quantidade consumida de água. No outro código C# tenho uma ihm que pega os valores do sensor ultrassônico e do sensor de fluxo, porem no código não estou conseguindo separar os valor recebidos na porta serial, gera um erro alguém pode me ajudar?

```
#define motor1 13
#define motor2 12
///////////////////////////////
      //SENSOR DE VAZÃO//
int Pulso; //VARIÁVEL PARA QUANTIDADE DE PULSOS.
int j=0; //VARIÁVEL PARA CONTAGEM
float vazaoagua; // Variável para armazenar o valor em L/min
float valormedia = 0; //VARIÁVEL PARA TIRAR A MÉDIA A CADA 1 MINUTO
//////////////////////////////

//PORTA EM QUE O SENSOR ULTRASSONICO ESTARA LIGADO...

#define trigPin 10 //PINO TRIG DO SENSOR NO PINO ANALÓGICO A1
#define echoPin 11 //PINO ECHO DO SENSOR NO PINO ANALÓGICO A0

unsigned int duracao = 0;
unsigned int distancia = 0;

int data;

////////////////////////////////////////////

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);// DEFINE VELOCIDADE CONEXÃO SERIAL

  //DEFINE OS PINOS DE ENTRADA E SAÍDA ...
  pinMode (trigPin, OUTPUT);// DEFINE SAÍDA
  pinMode (echoPin, INPUT);// DEFINE ENTRADA

  //MOTOR DA BOMBA 1
  pinMode(motor1, OUTPUT); //DEFINE O PINO COMO SAÍDA

   //MOTOR DA BOMBA 2
  pinMode(motor2, OUTPUT); //DEFINE O PINO COMO SAÍDA

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         //SENSOR DE FLUXO DE AGUA//
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(0, incrpulso, RISING); //CONFIGURA A PORTA DIGITAL 2, PARA INTERRUPÇÃO

}

void loop() {
   

  /////ACIONAMENTO DAS BOMBAS //////
  if(Serial.available()){
    data= Serial.read();

  //ACIONAMENTO DA BOMBA 1
    if(data== 'A'){
      digitalWrite(motor1, HIGH);
    }
    if(data== 'B'){
      digitalWrite(motor1, LOW);
    }
  //ACIONAMENTO DA BOMBA 2
    if(data== 'C'){
      digitalWrite(motor2, HIGH);
    }
    if(data== 'D'){
      digitalWrite(motor2, LOW);
    }

  }

  //////////////SENSOR ULTRASSONICO.../////////////////

    digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH); //ELEVA O SINAL DO TRIGGER
    delayMicroseconds(10);//POR 10 MICROSEGUNDOS
    digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

    //Armazena o valor em microsegundos  que foi lido
    duracao= pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

    distancia = duracao * 0.017175; //(340 * 100 / 10e6)

    Serial.print(distancia);
    Serial.println("cm");
    delay(500);

    ///////////////SENSOR DE FLUXO DE AGUA /////////////////////

   Pulso = 0; //Começa do 0 variável para contar os giros das pás internas,ek segundos
   sei(); //liga interrupção
   delay (2000); //Espera 2 segundos
   cli(); //Desliga interrupção

   vazaoagua = Pulso / 7.5; //Converte para Litros/minuto
   valormedia = valormedia+vazaoagua; //Soma a vazão para o calculo da valormedia
   j++;

   Serial.print(vazaoagua); //Imprime na serial o valor da vazão
   Serial.println("L"); //Imprime L/min
   if(j==60)

   {

    valormedia = valormedia/60; //Tira a valormedia dividindo por 60
    Serial.print("\n Media por minuto = "); //Imprime a frase valormedia por minuto =
    Serial.print(valormedia); //Imprime o valor da valormedia
    Serial.println(" Litros/minutos - "); //Imprime L/min
    valormedia = 0; //Torna variável valormedia = 0, para uma nova contagem
    j=0; //Torna a variável 0,para uma nova contagem
   }
    
   }

   void incrpulso ()
   { 
    Pulso++;
    }
```

Código C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace Abastecimento_de_tanque
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string serialDataIn;
        sbyte indexOfA, indexOfB;
        string dataSensor1, dataSensor2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //CLASSE ACIONAMENTO DA BOMBA 1...
        public void Ligarbomba1()
        {
            try
            {
                if (btnLigar.BackColor.Equals(Color.Green))
                {
                    btnLigar.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    serialPort1.Write("A");
                    btnLigar.Text = "BOMBA LIGADA";

                }
                else
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("B");
                    btnLigar.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    btnLigar.Text = "BOMBA DESLIGADA";
                }
              
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                //erro
                MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
            }
        }

        //CLASSE ACIONAMENTO DA BOMBA 2...
        public void LigaBomba2()
        {
            try
            {
                if (btnLigaBomba2.BackColor.Equals(Color.Green))
                {
                    btnLigaBomba2.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    serialPort1.Write("C");
                    btnLigaBomba2.Text = "BOMBA LIGADA";

                }
                else
                {
                    serialPort1.Write("D");
                    btnLigaBomba2.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    btnLigaBomba2.Text = "BOMBA DESLIGADA";
                }

            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                //erro
                MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
            }
        }

        //carrega a porta serial escolhida...
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //regra de negocio barra de status do tranque...
            lblVazio.Enabled = false;
            lblMedio.Enabled = false;
            lblCheio.Enabled = false;
            lblCetentaPorcento.Enabled = false;
            lblVintePorCento.Enabled = false;


            //classe buscar porta serial...
            BuscarPortSerial();

            //recebe leitura de dados da port aserial (do sensor ultrassonico)..
          

            //configurações do botão liga bomba 1
            btnLigar.Text = "BOMBA DESLIGADA";
            btnLigar.BackColor = Color.Green;

            //configurações do botão liga bomba 2
            btnLigaBomba2.Text = "BOMBA DESLIGADA";
            btnLigaBomba2.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }

        //---conexão com a porta serial
        public void BuscarPortSerial()
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen==false)
                {
                    serialPort1.Open();
                    lblPort.Text = serialPort1.PortName.ToString();
                    lblStatus.Text = "ON";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "OFF";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(erro.Message);
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        // fecha a porta serial ao dispositivo conectado...
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort1.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                erro.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        //acionamento da classe liga bomba 1...
        private void btnLigar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Ligarbomba1();
        }

        //acionamento da classe bomba 2
        private void btnLigaBomba2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LigaBomba2();
        }

        //recebe informaçãoe da porta serial...
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            serialDataIn = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(ProcessData));

            serialDataIn = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(FluxoAgua));
        }

        //barra de processebar mostra o status do tanque se esta cheio ou vazio...
        private void ProcessData(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                // MOSTRA O NÍVEL DO TANQUE
                indexOfA = Convert.ToSByte(serialDataIn.IndexOf("cm"));
                indexOfB = Convert.ToSByte(serialDataIn.IndexOf("L"));


                dataSensor1 = serialDataIn.Substring(0,indexOfA);
                //dataSensor2 = serialDataIn.Substring(indexOfB);

                lblPorcentagem.Text = dataSensor1;
                //lblConsumo.Text = dataSensor2;

                progressBar9.Value = Convert.ToInt16(dataSensor1);
                //textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(dataSensor2);

            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                lblInformacao.Text = (erro.Message);
            }
        }
        private void FluxoAgua(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            indexOfB = Convert.ToSByte(serialDataIn.IndexOf("L"));

            dataSensor2 = serialDataIn.Substring(indexOfB);

            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(dataSensor2);

        }

        //mostra o status do nível da caixa d'agua...
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // BuscarPortSerial();

            try
            {
              
                if (lblPorcentagem.Text == "15")
                {
                    //MENSAGEM DE TANQUE NÍVEL BAIXO
                    lblInformacao.Text=("TANQUE A 15% BOMBA LIGADA");
                    serialPort1.Write("A");
                    btnLigar.Text = "BOMBA LIGADA";
                    btnLigar.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
                if (lblPorcentagem.Text == "50")
                {
                    //
                   // listMensagens.Items.Add("TANQUE A 50% DO NÍVEL DESEJADO");
                }
                if (lblPorcentagem.Text == "75")
                {
                    //
                  //  listMensagens.Text = "TANQUE ESTA QUASE CHEIO.";
                }
                if (lblPorcentagem.Text == "90")
                {
                    //MENSAGEM DE TANQUE CHEIO
                    lblInformacao.Text = "TANQUE CHEIO, BOMBA DESLIGADA.";
                    serialPort1.Write("B");
                    btnLigar.Text = "BOMBA DESLIGADA";
                    btnLigar.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                lblInformacao.Text =(erro.Message);
            }
        }

        //Informa status de mensagens de erro e advertencia do sistema...
        private void picMensagem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmMensagens frm = new frmMensagens();
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Comprimento não pode ser menor que zero.

Tentei fazer algumas modificações mais sem sucesso.

Comment: Quando você fala que gera um erro, é importante você apresentar o erro gerado e também apontar no código onde ele ocorre. Tente sempre fazer a pergunta baseada em um [mcve]

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Comprimento não pode ser menor que zero.

Answer (score 0):

Esse é o que chamamos de um problema XY. A correção para o erro no código é simples, mas isso não significa que irá solucionar o seu problema.

O erro acontece por você tentar pegar parte da string começando da posição 0 até a -1, porque não foi encontrado nenhum "L" em `serialDataIn` no momento em que o método `FluxoAgua()` foi invocado. Agora, se deveria ter algum valor nessa string, é um outro ponto que você também vai ter que corrigir.

```
private void FluxoAgua(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var indexOfL = serialDataIn.IndexOf("L");   

    textBox1.Text = indexOfL > 0 ? serialDataIn.Substring(indexOfL): string.Empty;

}
```

O seu código apresenta diversos problemas de escopo, nomemclatura, conversões desnecessárias e redundância que você precisa revisar. Além de não fazer sentindo manter os índices em um escopo "global", isso pode causar diversos problemas na lógica quando executados qualquer um dos métodos.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!  Sim o Código esta cheio de coisas desnecessária, porem quando comecei tentei fazer de forma mais organizada, mais como é para estudo e um trabalho de curso fui testando umas coisas mudando outras, fiz uma salada kkkkk, mais com sua ajuda consegui resolver esse problema, Obrigado mesmo :)

Comment: Então aceite o post como resposta ou feche a pergunta :P